# Получение информации из файла шрифта

Tags: c#, шрифты, web-fonts

Всем привет. Возник такой вопрос, не могу найти ответов в гугле, может плохо ищу.
Возможно ли получить информацию о шрифте ttf, otf и файлов веб шрифтов такую как имя шрифта, начертание, курсив / не курсив, версию и в принципе всё, что есть в этом файле. Например, для дальнейшей генерации css файла с этими настройками шрифта.
Классы Font и PrivateFontCollection не подходят ибо с их помощью можно получить только название шрифта.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным вопросом?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628247/c-sharp-lib-for-processing-font-files-ttf-truetype-others

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить через powershell
Получить все свойства файла шрифта можно через `Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface`, на примере **$path** - полный путь к шрифту, сокращения не отрабатывают

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
$Typeface = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface -ArgumentList "$path"
```